# How to pass HTML attribute value dynamically with the help of variable into a CSS selector in protractor?

Tags: css, protractor

I have located the button on the row based on its value stored in the HTML attribute "title". Now I have to pass dynamic value to this HTML attribute "title". Hence I have declared it in variable, But I'm not sure on how to pass this variable into the CSS Selector.

Here is my CSS Selector:

```
btnMoreNewRole = element(by.css("//input[@title='Access']/ancestor::tr/td[16]"))
```

In my above CSS Selector I have to pass the value of the HTML attribute title as a variable. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below

```
const title = //Your dynamic title

btnMoreNewRole = element(by.xpath('//input[@title="'+title+'"]/ancestor::tr/td[16]'))
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I'm getting the following error: - Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: @Poovin, change to `by.xpath` instead of `by.css`